# ModRewrite only works for some options

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess file is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([0-9]+) /blog.php?post=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/page/([0-9]+) /blog.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^work/([0-9]+) /work.php?ID=$1
```

The work.php rule is working, but the two blog rules aren't.  They used to all work, but I recently moved my server.  Any ideas why this would be?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Woah, I noticed that I had a work folder, but no blog folder, so I made one, and now this works. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set up a (virtual) server on my local Apache 2.2 installation, running PHP 5.2 as a module. The server's document root contained only php files to (simplistically) process the examples you gave above (just echoing the parameters from $_GET). My .htaccess file at the document root contained only what you specified above, and nothing else. The document root did not contain the subdirectories /work or /blog (or /blog/post or /blog/page).

My setup did not have any problems at all rewriting the SEO-friendly URLs to the proper PHP files, which in turn echoed the parameter values I expected from $_GET.

There is something other than mod_rewrite requiring the existence of the subdirectories, and Apache is hitting (and thus requiring) it before it processes the rewrite rules. Not sure what it is, but it does not appear to be mod_rewrite, given the rules you have above.